# Mysql - String A, B and B, A should be same

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below,

```
taskId taskList
1      A, B
2      C, F, H
```

when I query,

```
select count(*) from task_list where taskList='A, B';
```

OP: 1

But for,

```
select count(*) from task_list where taskList='B, A';
```

OP: 0

I am expecting 'A, B' and 'B, A' are same.

How to achieve this?

Comment: To clarify does  "C, F, H"  or  "F, H,C" or "H,F C" count as same? What about "H, F"? I think you will get a better response if you help us a little more.

Comment: Maybe use the in operator, like `taskList in ('a,b', 'b, a')` this is similar to an or logic

Comment: @Rippo for 'H, F' it should be 0. because there is no taskList same as 'H, F'

Comment: @MMMMS and my first point in comment?

Comment: Denormalize your data. Stop storing lists as a comma separated string. Each task should be in a separate row.

Comment: @Rippo yes that first condition must be 1 because task C, F and H is there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using exact comparasion using the equal sign. In an exact comparasion, 'A, B' is not the same as 'B, A'.

As someone else mention, you sould denormalize your data.

If that's not an option, use the like command instead. Something like this:

```
select count(*) from task_list where (taskList LIKE '%A%' AND taskList LIKE '%B%');
```

Hope this helps.
Regards